# will different action objects created in struts2 for different methods called of same action?

Tags: struts2

I have an Action class with 3 methods. I know that for every request to Action class it will create an instance. But here I'm requesting the same Action class with different method.

How many objects will be created? 3, or only 1 ?

How can I find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creation of your action instances does not depend on the number of methods that you have in your action class. It solely depends on the number of request that you make. So if you make `n` requests, `n` instances are created. And i believe the instance is destroyed once the action class instance is done serving the request.

Comment: You are correct. The lifespan of the action instance is bound to the HTTP request/response.

Comment: it is possible to chain actions so it is possible for multiple action instances to be created per request but you would have to knowingly want this